# Spree does not work with the protected_attributes gem installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree, rails-upgrade

I am upgrading my application from **`rails 3.2`** to **`rails 4`**. I am following this Railscast [**`#415 Upgrading to Rails 4`**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4?view=asciicast)

When I tried to start my `rails server` after adding `protected_attributes` gem in my `Gemfile` spree is giving me this error and I am not able to start the server.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Other gems
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.7'
#...
gem 'spree', '~> 3.1.0'

# Gems for upgrading to rails 4
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'activeresource'
gem 'activerecord-session_store'
gem 'activerecord-deprecated_finders'
```

**Error:**

```
$ rails server

***************************************************************************
[FATAL] Spree does not work with the protected_attributes gem installed!
You MUST remove this gem from your Gemfile. It is incompatible with Spree.
***************************************************************************
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Spree 3.1 is already using strong parameters. Is there a particular reason you need to keep using protected_attributes?

Comment: Yes, untill the migration process is done I need `protected_attributes` gem

Comment: Or I will have to remove all `attr_accessible` then only my app will start